# How to clear stale hashed search path in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

Previously my bash script was pointing to /path1 but I moved it to under /path2, now if I do "type myscript" it's still pointing to /path1, how do I solve this?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's this:

```
hash -r
```

Comment: I closed my bash session and started a new one and that solved the problem too. I thought I tried that before, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @grokus It's nice not to have to start a new shell - especially if you're logged in over ssh - but a new shell should do it.

Comment: @Telemachus, thanks. Next time I run into this, I will try "hash -r".

Comment: @Telemachus, can you vote my question up? I have more than 100 reputations on all other SE sites but not this one. It sucks to have 1 point, I can't even vote up anything. :(

Comment: @grokus I'll vote it up, but you must *promise* to put the question back. Otherwise, this thread is getting awfully silly. (I currently have an answer in search of a question.) Also, can't you accept answers no matter what your point level is? (That gets you points as well.)

Comment: @grokus - Not related to this question, but FYI, if you've got more than 200rep on any SE site you should be due a +100 bonus. You need to unlink this account, then goto the site with >200 and relink - see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/should-all-linked-accounts-get-the-100-bonus).

Comment: @Telemachus. Done. Sorry about that.